# change FAT16 partition UUID

Tags: partition, uuid, vfat

I have created a `FAT16` formatted partition on my USB stick using

```
mkdosfs /dev/sdb1
```

when I plug in my stick, it appears in `/dev/` as:

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/ABCD-1234
```

How can I change the UUID of the disk to something else than `ABCD-1234` ?

**UPDATE**

tune2fs does not seem to work:

```
# tune2fs /dev/sdb1 -U AAAA-1111
tune2fs 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
tune2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb1
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

**UPDATE2**

I have installed `mtools 4.0.17-1` on Debian Wheezy, but the `mlabel` command does not work:

```
# mlabel -N aaaa1111 /dev/sdb1
Mtools version 4.0.17, dated June 29th, 2011
Usage: mlabel [-vscVn] [-N serial] drive:
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mtools` comes with an utility `mlabel` which might do the job.

```
mlabel -N aaaa1111 -i /dev/sdb1 ::
```

Apart from that you might have to resort to a hex editor. The `dosfstools` only lets you change the label using the `fatlabel` command (which `mlabel` does too, just without the volume id).

If you're willing to re-create the filesystem from scratch, the value can also be supplied via `mkfs.vfat -i VOLUME-ID`.

Comment: this does not work. Please see my update

Comment: Oh, and if you add a `:`?

Comment: The correct syntax would be `mlabel -N aaaa1111 -i /dev/sdb1 ::`, to specify `/dev/sdb1` as the "image" to use.

Comment: This program uses strange DOS drive letter names... `mtoolstest` might list them. Sorry, I relied too much on the manpage for this one... ;)

Answer (score 1):

mtools work:

```
mlabel -N $(uuidgen | head -c8) f:
```

You just have to configure `/etc/mtools.conf`:

```
drive f: file="/dev/sdb1"
```

Comment: Why not just `mlabel -N $(uuidgen | head -c8) -i  /dev/sdb1 ::`?

Answer (score -1):

use below command

`tune2fs partition_name  -U useb_id_what_you_want`

use `uuidgen` to generate random UUID

Comment: `tune2fs` does not work. Please see my update for details.